# How to replace a column value by its previous value with condition

Tags: sql

| Row 1 | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New business |
| 2 | Adjustment |
| 3 | Adjustment |
| 4 | Renewal |
| 5 | Adjustment |
| 6 | Cancellation |

> The goal is to replace the all the Category 'Adjustment' with the above values.

Output:

| Row 1 | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New business |
| 2 | New business |
| 3 | New business |
| 4 | Renewal |
| 5 | Renewal |
| 6 | Cancellation |

Comment: Do you actually have an column that defines the order, like an `id` or a timestamp column?  Remember that SQL rows do not have an inherent order, so "previous value" does not have any meaning.

Comment: Yes it does have a timestamp column.

Comment: Do you want an ISO compliant solution or should you [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: It's a guessing game unless you specify the RDBMS, where to replace (in SELECT against the table or inside the table itself) and what to do if "Adjustment" happens to be the very first row (set to NULL, leave it, or set to something else).  Generally you can access the previous value using the window function `lag` like `lag(category) over (order by row)`  in a select statement to access the previous value and swap it based on the condition. _This function is ISO compliant for a long time now [SQL:2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003)_

Answer (score 1):

I was going to tell you it couldn't be done, but it can.  I invented a "row number" column here, but you can substitute your timestamp.  This is sqlite3:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    row integer,
    category text
);

INSERT INTO data VALUES
    (1, "New business"),
    (2, "Adjustment"),
    (3, "Adjustment"),
    (4, "Renewal"),
    (5, "Adjustment"),
    (6, "Cancellation");

UPDATE data SET category=(
    SELECT category FROM data d2 
        WHERE d2.category != 'Adjustment' 
          AND d2.row < data.row
        ORDER BY d2.row DESC LIMIT 1
    )
WHERE category='Adjustment';
```

Basically, the subquery selects the non-adjustments row that has the largest row number.